# IMAP not opening when trying to fetch Hotmail emails in CakePHP

Tags: php, email, cakephp, imap

With the below code i am trying to fetch emails from Hotmail.
On my system localhost this code is working fine but on my hosting server this code is not working.

IMAP is enable on hosting server.

**`PHP Warning:  imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap-mail.outlook.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX`**

**CakePHP Controller code:**

```
$username = 'myusername@hotmail.com';
    $password = 'myusernamepassword';
    set_time_limit(3000);

    /* try to connect */
    $inbox = imap_open('{imap-mail.outlook.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX',$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Mail Server: ' . imap_last_error());

    /* grab emails */

    $emails = imap_search($inbox,'UNSEEN');

    /* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
    if($emails) {
        /* begin output var */
        $output = '';
        /* put the newest emails on top */
        rsort($emails);
        /* for every email... */
        $count = 1;

        foreach($emails as $email_number) {
            $head = imap_header($inbox, $email_number);
            /* get information specific to this email */
            $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
            $message = imap_body($inbox,$email_number,2);
            $subject = $this->decode_imap_text($overview[0]->subject);              


        }

        // echo $output;
    }

    /* close the connection */
    imap_close($inbox);
```

[image]

Comment: Give it try with `{imap-mail.outlook.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX`

Comment: But same code is working on local system in wamp

Comment: I can see SSL support enable on your server but when you try to run your code then your server check for `Secure Socket Layer to encrypt the session`. And in your local server may be OpenSSL support is enable that why its working on your local wamp.

Comment: @hardiksolanki can we chat on Stackoverflow ?
I have not find any solution on google or stackoverflow..

Answer (score 3):

If it is working correctly on localhost then there may be **port 993 OR imap protocol is blocked on server by firewall etc.** (High Probability for this error)

if you have access to hosting server then check for firewall. otherwise contact hosting administrator or look for another hosting.

**Edit:** Get more detailed error by [imap_last_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-last-error.php), [imap_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-errors.php) AND [imap_alerts](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-alerts.php) functions.

Comment: Thank You. i have contacted with my hosting service.. but they say everything is enable..but still same problem...

Comment: @PuzzledBoy ok then try following workarounds: **remove INBOX from first parameter** OR **adding novalidate-cert** (`{imap-mail.outlook.com:993/ssl/novalidate-cert}`). And also display error by `imap_last_error` function to see more detailed error.